# Writing Recordset to textfile from Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

The code below works correctly and writes the recordset to a text file:

```
  Set rs = cnn.Execute(Sql)
  Dim objFSO As Object
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set txtfile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("d:\Test.txt", True)
  txtfile.Write rs.GetString
```

However, the output in the textfile is tab separated. As I wanted the fields in the textfile to be separated by "|" symbol, the last line above was replaced with

```
txtfile.Write (rs.GetString(adClipString, , "|", , ""))
```

It shows a runtime error 3001 with the message that the arguments are of the wrong type, out of acceptable range, conflict etc.  How do I fix the problem.

Comment: All args are optional, https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_getstring.asp, so just the colDel arg is needed I would think also, no real need for the enclosing brackets around it all.

Comment: In Tools > References, have you checked the box next to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" (or any other version of that library)?